# Why is there a difference between get and put requests?

Tags: json, api, http, security, encryption

Why Is there a difference between put and get requests? From what I can see, put requests are used when you want to send some information to the server, ussually in the form of a json with your request. Get requests are for when you want some information from the server.

However, I think we can also send messages with get requests and we can return information with a put request.

```
get("https://xx.xx.xx/?message=*encrypted json*")
```

The encrypted json can still be read by the server.

So what is the difference between a get and put request?

Comment: HTTP GET with a side effect: almost always a security bug.

Comment: How? Aren't you just submitting urls which are processed as strings? Where's the vulnerability?

Comment: `<img src=“https://example.com/closeaccount?deleteAll=true&force=true” />`. Embed that in, e.g. a StackOverflow post, everyone who has an account at example.com finds their accounts erased. GETs should not have side effects :)